# Coffeescript compare two possible null/undefined values

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following statement in `JavaScript` which I want to convert to `CoffeeScript`:

```
var foo = function(category) {
    return selectedCategory == category ? "my-custom-class" : "";
}
```

Now the above comparison will return `"my-custom-class"` in the case where
`selectedCategory == null` and `category == undefined` which is something that I want.

However when I try to do this in CoffeeScript:

```
foo = (category) -> if selectedCategory is category then "my-custom-class" else ""
```

the comparison in `JavaScript` becomes `selectedCategory === category` which obviously gives me `""` when `selectedCategory` is null and `category` is undefined. Is there a way I can relax the `===` or describe the condition in a better way?

Comment: The above link gives you a workaround with  `\`==\`` alright, but is there a "proper" CoffeeScript way of writing this expression?

Comment: In as concise a manner? Don't think so. You could write `foo = (category) -> if not (selectedCategory or category) or (selectedCategory is category) then "my-custom-class" else ""` to succeed when both are false-y, and otherwise compare them with strict equality.